# Number of SE Sites in site list tooltip is wrong

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, tooltips

It's generally accepted the Stack Exchange has 173 sites. It's shown in the login page, [stackexchange.com](https://www.stackexchange.com), and in the Site Tour. For example (from the Meta Site Tour):

[image: Meta Stack Exchange is part of the StackExchange(R) network of 173 Q&A communities.]

However, the tooltip from mousing over the sites list reads:

[image: A list of all 174 Stack Exchange sites]

Since it has the wrong number (compared to everything else), shouldn't the tooltip be modified to read 173, not 174?

EDIT: I clicked on the Stack Exchange logo while using SuperUser and got this:
[image: 174 Q&A sites]
It says "174 Q&A communities".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Area 51 in the site drop down]

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is not a "Q&A community" per se, although I guess [the Discussion site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) technically qualifies…but it's still a Stack Exchange site, so 173 + 1

In the [stackexchange.com site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#answers) it's given a mention in the footer instead of being listed along with the other sites.

Comment: Now it says [174 Q&A sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOAk0.png).